# pandas: create a series of dates that include only certain days of the week skipping weekends

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a little script (I'm not the only author) that creates a pandas series filled in by dates without weekends.
Various tasks are distributed on these dates, and depending on how long each task takes, its completion may take a different number of days. The question is, how can I take into account only certain days (for example, only Wednesday and Thursday), not all 5 days from Monday to Friday?

```
durations = [4, 8, 2, 16, 5]
hours_per_day = 7
start_date = "2021-07-01"

arr = np.array(durations)
bins = [0]
bins.extend([x[-1] for x in np.array_split(np.arange(np.sum(arr)), np.ceil(np.sum(arr)/hours_per_day))])
# [0, 6, 13, 20, 27, 34]
totals = np.cumsum(arr)
# [ 4 12 14 30 35]
idx = np.digitize(totals, bins, right=True)-1
# [0 1 2 4 5]
start_deltas = np.pad(idx, (1, 0))[:-1]
# [0 0 1 2 4] searched deltas
```

Then I create data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"task":[f"task{x}" for x in range(len(durations))],
                   "duration": durations,
                   "delta":start_deltas})
df["start_date"] = start_date
df["start_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_date"])
df["start_date"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["start_date"] + BDay(pd.to_timedelta(x["delta"], "d").days), axis=1)
df["end_date"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["start_date"] + BDay(pd.to_timedelta(x["duration"]//hours_per_day, "d").days), axis=1)
```

In the last 2 rows, I want to filter the days by the weekday index. When I try to apply weekday (and its variations) or day_name(), there is a mistake about the concatenation of str and business day. I know the reason, but I've run out of ideas on how to implement this filtration by day index.

Comment: You can probably use the CustomBusinessDay offset specifying the weekmask:
`pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(holidays=None, weekmask='Wed Thu Sat Sun')` though I'm not entirely sure exactly what your need

Comment: What is the desired output for your example?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen the desired output is a data frame with the tasks' names, their duration, dates of start working on these tasks, and dates of finishing.

Comment: @ALollz CustomBDay doesn't fit in my case, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used CustomBusinessDay as ALollz advised. It works.

```
CDay(pd.to_timedelta(x["delta"], "d").days, weekmask='Wed Thu Sat Sun'), axis=1)
```